# Dialog gets hidden by the top navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Primefaces 5.3, and [AdminLTE 2](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview) as a template for my website (Which based on bootsrap).

The problem is when I open a dialog box, this dialog gets hidden by the top navbar, and this topbar doesn't get disabled I can still click on its links.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

As you can see in that picture a portion of the dialog box is hidden by the top nav bar.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Which dialog box. What navbar.... Please share code or screenshot to help us understand the problem.

Comment: @NasirT please check my edit

Comment: is the top navbar postion fixed?

Comment: @GvM yes it is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a sample code to work and check your issue. Here is a probable solution that i can suggest to you. Check the `z-index` of the navbar and the dialog. Try setting `z-index` for both where the dialog box `z-index` value is greater than the navbar.